# getting error while Inserting data while using RadControls

Tags: webforms, ado.net-entity-data-model, rad-controls

Error:

> Unable to update the EntitySet 'ClientFeedBack' because it has a DefiningQuery and no `<InsertFunction>` element exists in the `<ModificationFunctionMapping>` element to support the current operation.

Code:

```cs
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    ProTrakEntities1 objEntity = new ProTrakEntities1(); 
    TextBox txtTitle = DetailsView1.FindControl("txtTask") as TextBox;
    RadComboBox cmbStatus = DetailsView1.FindControl("cmbStatus") as RadComboBox;  

    RadComboBox cmbTaskType = DetailsView1.FindControl("cmbTasktype") as RadComboBox;  
    RadComboBox cmbTaskPriorty = DetailsView1.FindControl("cmbPriority") as RadComboBox;

    string Description = (DetailsView1.FindControl("RadEditor1") as RadEditor).Content;

    ClientFeedBack objResource = new ClientFeedBack();
    objResource.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    objResource.Description = Description;

    objResource.TaskPriorityID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTaskPriorty.SelectedValue);
    objResource.TaskTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTaskType.SelectedValue);

    objEntity.AddToClientFeedBacks(objResource);
    objEntity.SaveChanges();

    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "mykey", "CloseAndRebind('navigateToInserted');", true);
}
```

My table name is `ClientFeedBack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the primary key, check if you table ClientFeedBack has primary key defined or not.